# How can cytoscape be used as part of a Vue component?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm looking to deploy cytoscape as part of a vue component.  Is there a preferred method?  Can the cs props be fed through Vue props?

Comment: Please just read through the [docs](https://js.cytoscape.org/). Vue actually supports cytoscape.js as a component (see [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cytoscape)) and there are [docs](https://rcarcasses.github.io/vue-cytoscape/) about that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation

Somewhere in the template element

```html
    <div id="cy-wrapper">
      <div id="cy" ref="cy"></div>
    </div>
```

And in the script, `mounted` hook:

```js
      import('cytoscape')
        .then((cy) => {
          // async load cytoscape
          cytoscape = cy.default;
        })
        .then(() => {
          // start init

          const element = document.createElement('div');
          element.setAttribute('id', 'cy-mounting-point');

          this.$refs.cy.appendChild(element);

          this.cyInstance = Object.freeze(
            cytoscape({
              container: element,
              // some configs here 
            })
          );

          // Force it to be painted again, 
          // so that when added to the DOM it doesn't show a blank graph
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.resizeGraph();
          });

        })
```

The `resizeGraph` is simply a function in `methods` attr:

```js
      resizeGraph() {
        if (this.cyInstance) {
          this.cyInstance.resize();
        }
      },
```